# change CSS first child element when hover second or third element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the CSS of first child element when hovering second or  third element

My HTML, I want to show "no-thumb" and hide "has-thumb" when hovering second or  third element

```css
.TopList .lists:hover .has-thumb,
.no-thumb {
  display: none;
}

.TopList .lists:hover .has-thumb {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopList">
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="has-thumb" style="display: block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb"></div>
    <div class="has-thumb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb"></div>
    <div class="has-thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not directly possible with CSS alone - CSS can only select downwards or to the right in the DOM tree.

Comment: @misorude Of course it's possible. The question is tagged with JavaScript as well as CSS.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I overlooked the javascript tag, comment edited. (If they _want_ a JS solution, they should show what they already tried already though.)

Comment: Do u want to show the second and third when hovering first element?

Comment: If you want to do it in pure CSS nevertheless, you could format those elements based on `.TopList:hover` - and then re-set their formatting to “normal” state explicitly again when the first child itself gets hovered.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript solution would be to simply add or remove a pre-made CSS class that hides an element as the second and third items are moused over and moused out.

```js
// Get references to the elements that will be shown/hidden
let noThumb = document.querySelector(".no-thumb");
let hasThumb = document.querySelector(".has-thumb");

// Set up an event handler for when the entire list is hovered
document.querySelector(".TopList").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){ 
   // Check to see if the element being hovered is one we care about
   if(event.target.parentNode.classList.contains("hover")) {
     // Hide and show the elements.
     noThumb.classList.remove("hidden");
     hasThumb.classList.add("hidden");
   }
});

document.querySelector(".TopList").addEventListener("mouseout", function(event){
   if(event.target.parentNode.classList.contains("hover")) {
     noThumb.classList.add("hidden");
     hasThumb.classList.remove("hidden");
   }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
.lists { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="TopList">
   <div class="lists">
       <div class="no-thumb hidden">no thumb</div>
       <div class="has-thumb">has thumb</div>
   </div>
   <div class="lists hover">
       <div class="no-thumb">x</div>
       <div class="has-thumb">x</div>
   </div>
   <div class="lists hover">
       <div class="no-thumb">x</div>
       <div class="has-thumb">x</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "previous element" selector in css but you can use the :hover selector of the parent element together with :first-child

See snippet: Show no-thumb of first element when hovering over 2nd or 3rd element.

```css
.no-thumb {
  display: none;
}

.TopList:hover .lists:first-child .has-thumb {
  display: none;
}

.TopList:hover .lists:first-child .no-thumb {
  display: block;
}

.TopList:hover .lists:first-child:hover .has-thumb {
  display: block;
}

.TopList:hover .lists:first-child:hover .no-thumb {
  display: none;
}

.lists {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopList">
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb">no-thumb</div>
    <div class="has-thumb">has-thumb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb">no-thumb</div>
    <div class="has-thumb">has-thumb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <div class="no-thumb">no-thumb</div>
    <div class="has-thumb">has-thumb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The :hover is triggering for the parent '.TopList'. Since there is no margin between elements in your example, it seems okay. But imagine if there is some gap between the elements '.lists'. the hover will trigger on these gaps also.

Comment: Sure, margins would be a problem if there were some.

Answer (score 0):

you should use javascript or jQuery

```
jQuery('.lists').mouseover(function () {

    if (!jQuery(this).is(':first-child')) {

         jQuery('.lists:first-child .no-thumb').show();
         jQuery('.lists:first-child .has-thumb').hide();
    }
}).mouseleave(function () {
         jQuery('.lists:first-child .no-thumb').hide();
         jQuery('.lists:first-child .has-thumb').show();
})
```

for do that in vanilla javascrpt your HTML changes in this

```
<div class="TopList" id="TopList">
            <div class="lists">
                <div class="no-thumb" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="has-thumb" style="display: block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="lists" onmouseenter="javascript:overfunction()" onmouseout="javascript:blurfunction()">
                <div class="no-thumb"></div>
                <div class="has-thumb"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="lists" onmouseenter="javascript:overfunction()" onmouseout="javascript:blurfunction()">
                <div class="no-thumb"></div>
                <div class="has-thumb"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the scripts in this

```
<script>
function overfunction(){

    var firstEl =  document.getElementById('TopList').children[0]

    firstEl.children[0].style.display = 'block'
    firstEl.children[1].style.display = 'none'
}

function blurfunction(){

    var firstEl =  document.getElementById('TopList').children[0]

    firstEl.children[0].style.display = 'none'
    firstEl.children[1].style.display = 'block'
}
</script>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try with this, It is working as expected only CSS is used.

```css
.TopList:hover .lists:first-child .no-thumb{ 
 display:block !important; 
 } 
  .TopList:hover .lists:first-child .has-thumb{ 
 display:none !important; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="TopList">
   <div class="lists">
      
        <div class="no-thumb" style="display:none">no-thumb</div> 
        <div class="has-thumb" style="display: block">has-thumb</div> 
   </div>
   <div class="lists">
       <div class="no-thumb">second-no</div>
       <div class="has-thumb">second-has</div>
   </div>
   <div class="lists">
       <div class="no-thumb">third-no</div>
       <div class="has-thumb">third-has</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
See This solution and use accordingly-
```

Click here (https://codepen.io/vishnavneet/pen/XWrzgxb/)